# How to install VirtualBox in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: "No suitable module for running kernel found"

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I have a fresh 12.04 LTS installation. I have installed linux-headers-generic as well as build-essential. When I install virtualbox, I get the following error:

```
Building initial module for 3.13.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules
   ...done.
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.6) ...
```

Full log here:
http://paste.yt/P3183.html

I have checked the make.log file. It is here:
http://paste.yt/P3184.html

Comment: The VB version you use is completely outdated. Get this version instead: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: This is the one that is provided via Ubuntu software mirrors (apt-get)?

Comment: No... In Ubuntu reps, many softwares are outdated. Use the link I gave to download the package and open it. It will open 'Software Center' and allow you to install. Your problem is most probably your VB version don't work with the last Linux kernel.